# how to change the domain name from my local ip to "mywebpage" in glassfish 3.1.2?

Tags: jsp, glassfish, dns

I'm tryng to change the domain of my JSP web site. When i want to show my page to another computer on the same LAN I have to give the IP of my pc to him like

```
http://192.168.77.232:8080/MyWebSite/index.html
```

is there a way to change that to

```
http://MyWebSite/index.html
```

or

```
http://domainname:8080/MyWebSite/index.html
```

I have tried these instructions with no result. 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjsdi/index.html

As additional data my IDE is NetBeans 7.1.2

Comment: To respond to other computers with a name requires to change the network configuration, I think. You'd have to be registered with the desired name in the local DNS. This is not something that can be achieved just by configuring Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to Glassfish but i've had luck edditing the local machines host files to point the address `http://MyWebSite/` to the machines IP `192.168.77.232:8080`

```
192.168.77.232:8080 MyWebSiteAddress
```

A graphical guide can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)